# Convert date string to required date string format

Tags: iphone

I have parsed .ics file and get the start date as string , the string contains value like this 20100803T130451Z (this is formated date string), I want to convert this string into my required string format ....

My required format of date string is   (Tuesday - May 25,2010 (like this))

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ole is right, here some sample code.

This:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"];
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

should do the conversion of the NSString to a NSDate. To then get your desired date format you can change the NSDateFormatters dateFormat. Like this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dddd - MMMM dd,yyy"];
NSString* myNiceLookingDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
[dateFormatter release];
```

That should work, although I did not test it but it will get you at least closer to the result.

have fun,
phil.

Comment: This code only works in 3.2 not work in iphone sim 4.0.Any ideas ?

Comment: yes, you are right - tested it: It seems like the dateFormatter is a little bit more sensitive in iOS 4. Setting the dateFormat the following way: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"]; should fix your problem. I corrected it in the post.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `NSDateFormatter` to convert the date string to a `NSDate` object.
2. Create a second `NSDateFormatter` (or change the format string of the first) to convert the `NSDate` back to a string.